# AngularJs - set $timeout delay dynamically in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have this next method declared in a directive to show slides with a delay :

```
            var timer;

            var sliderFunc = function(){
                timer = $timeout(function(){
                    scope.next();
                    timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, 5000);
                }, 5000);
            };

            sliderFunc();
```

With this example, everything is good.

But i want to set a different delay between first (1000) and others slides (5000).
So i tried to set 'delay' parameter dynamically as this example :

```
            var timer;
            scope.timeout = 5000;

            var sliderFunc = function(){
                timer = $timeout(function(){
                    scope.next();
                    timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, scope.timeout);
                }, scope.timeout);
            };

            sliderFunc();
```

In the first occurrence, delay is good, but in the next steps 'scope.timeout' is undefined.

Does any one have an idea how to solve it?

---

**UPDATE 1 :**

If i inspect my code in the first occurence, 'delay' (equal to scope.timeout in the last example) is equal to '5000' when i enter in 'slideFunc', but is undefined in second function and on the next steps :

[image: delay to timeout method]

**UPDATE 2 :**

This is my entire directive :

'delay' is supposed to be set in my directive declaration.

```
angular.module('myApp.central.directives', []).
directive('slider', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          list: '=',
          delay: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.currentIndex = 0;

            scope.next = function(){
                if (scope.currentIndex < scope.list.length -1) {
                    scope.currentIndex++;
                } else {
                    scope.currentIndex = 0;
                }
            };

            scope.$watch('currentIndex',function(){
                // some code useless for this problem
            });

            /* Start: For Automatic slideshow*/

            var timer;
            scope.delay = 5000;

            var sliderFunc = function(){
                timer = $timeout(function(){
                    scope.next();
                    timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, scope.delay);
                }, scope.delay);
            };

            sliderFunc();

            scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
                $timeout.cancel(timer);
            });

            /* End : For Automatic slideshow*/

        },
        templateUrl: 'partials/widgets/slider-template.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I noticed that the first piece of code is actually working:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6f05wn8/1/.

What is next() function?

Comment: I don't think 'next()' function do something important for this problem. I updated subject with my entire directive

Comment: I tried to replace 'scope.delay = 5000' by 'var delay = 5000' and it works. The problem seems to come from scope. And i need to use 'delay' from scope because it's supposed to be a directive parameter.

Comment: Sorry, but it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/mk3yywz5/

Comment: I reproduced my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/2hoLadsL/2/
'delay' parameter need to be defined in html. i thought i was able to define default value by setting 'scope.delay = 5000;' in directive code but I can't.
Thanks @MichaelZucchetta ;)

Answer (score 0):

When using two way bindings you can't just bind a scalar value such as an integer. You must bind to a property of an object. This is because of the way it stores a reference to the object. Basically anywhere you use a binding make sure there is a dot.

For example

```
$scope.test = {
 v: [],
 z: 1000
}

<div ng-app="myApp.central.directives" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <slider list="test.v" delay="test.z"></slider>
</div>
```